# regex: change "white space" chracter and - character to null

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [-0.532681, 'foo sai', 0],
    [1.490752, 'bar', 1],
    [-1.387326, 'foo-', '-'],
    [0.814772, 'baz', ' - '],     
    [-0.222552, ' -', '   -'],
    [-1.176781,  'qux', '- '],         
], columns='A B C'.split())

print(df)
print('-------------------------------')

print(df.replace(r'[^\w][\s]', np.nan, regex=True))
```

how i replace any `whitespace` character and `-` with regex?

with my code, return this:

```
          A        B    C
0 -0.532681  foo sai    0
1  1.490752      bar    1
2 -1.387326     foo-    -
3  0.814772      baz  NaN
4 -0.222552        -  NaN
5 -1.176781      qux  NaN
```

```
but return that i expect is this:<br>
              A        B    C
    0 -0.532681  foo sai    0
    1  1.490752      bar    1
    2 -1.387326     foo-  Nan
    3  0.814772      baz  NaN
    4 -0.222552      Nan  NaN
    5 -1.176781      qux  NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
df.replace(r'^[\s-]+$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
          A        B    C
0 -0.532681  foo sai  0.0
1  1.490752      bar  1.0
2 -1.387326     foo-  NaN
3  0.814772      baz  NaN
4 -0.222552      NaN  NaN
5 -1.176781      qux  NaN
```

The `^[\s-]+$` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[\s-]+`  -  one or more whitespace or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: for my education, does this not replace the space in `foo bar` due to `^ & $` respectively ?

Comment: @Manakin Yes, these are string anchors, see [Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).